# Reading the arguments of my command and using them in the command

Tags: macros, arguments

My question is about reading and using the arguments of a custom created command using `\def`.

Let's say I have the command `\mytestcommand` and I want to read and use it's arguments (optional and mandatory of unknown number)

I have the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{NumOptionalArgFound}
\newcounter{NumMandatoryArgFound}
\xdef\MaxMandArgs{3}


\makeatletter
\def\SearchForOptional{%
   \@ifnextchar[%
   {\FoundOptional}
   {\relax}
}
\def\FoundOptional[#1]{%
   \stepcounter{NumOptionalArgFound}%
   \xdef\curOptArg{#1}%
   \global\expandafter\let\csname OptionalArgument\arabic{NumOptionalArgFound}\endcsname\curOptArg%
   \@ifnextchar[%
   {\FoundOptional}
   {\SearchForMandatory}
}
\def\SearchForMandatory{%
   \@ifnextchar\bgroup%
   {\CheckIfMandatory}
   {\relax}
}
\def\CheckIfMandatory#1{%
   \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{\bgroup}=0%
      #1%
   \else
      \ifnum\arabic{NumMandatoryArgFound}<\MaxMandArgs%
         \stepcounter{NumMandatoryArgFound}%
         \xdef\curManArg{#1}%
         \global\expandafter\let\csname MandatoryArgument\arabic{NumMandatoryArgFound}\endcsname\curManArg%
         \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\SearchForMandatory%
      \else
         #1%
      \fi
   \fi
}
\makeatother

\def\mytestcommand{
\xdef\MaxMandArgs{2}
\SearchForOptional
}


\def\printArgs{
\foreach \i in {1,...,\theNumOptionalArgFound}{
Opt Arg \i: \csname OptionalArgument\i\endcsname\par
}

\foreach \i in {1,...,\theNumMandatoryArgFound}{
Mand Arg \i: \csname MandatoryArgument\i\endcsname\par
}
}


\begin{document}

\mytestcommand[Optional 1][Optional Second]{first Mand}{second Mand}{thirdMand}\bgroup noMand \egroup

\printArgs
\end{document}
```

This code works fine and finds-saves the optional and mandatory arguments of ot. My problem is that if i try to use one of the counters or of the arguments inside the definition of `\mytestcommand` it fails to find the number or the argument.

More specific, I would like to use `\printArgs` command inside of `\mytestcommand` definition... (So I can know I am able to use the arguments inside my command definition).

The problem appears if I change the definition of `\mytestcommand` to:

```
\def\mytestcommand{
\xdef\MaxMandArgs{2}
\SearchForOptional
\printArgs
}
```

Thank's=Thanks

PS: I am looking for a LaTeX2e solution, but LaTeX3 is probably helpful for other users... I would like not to use packages that I know exist for such jobs but if possible, "primary" LaTeX commands like mine...

Comment: Just curious: why not L3?

Comment: @cfr I am going to use these commamds in a book about LaTeX2e... If later I manage to learn some more LaTeX3 and be able to write a LaTeX3 book too, I will appreciate the answers in LaTeX3... but for now I am looking for LaTeX2e solutions and if possible without usage of extra packages (when possible)

Comment: You are against packages, but you're happy to load ***Ti*k*Z***, of all things?

Comment: Your code doesn't demonstrate the problem. You haven't shown how you're trying to use `\printargs` or whatever in the command. You've just posted code for the bit you're not having problems with?

Comment: If you mean tikz... yes... My book is a book for physicist... And this package is a must in my work and in the way I use LaTeX for teaching physics...

Comment: Sorry for that (about not demonstrate the problem)... I thought it was clear... I will edit my post.

Comment: You are commenting line endings you don't need to and failing to comment those you do need to, by the way.

Comment: Off-topic: Who is Thank and what belongs to her/him?

Comment: Thank you about the comment that I am not commenting line endings correct... I don't really know the rules yet... but I am going to learn about it soon... I edited the question to demonstrate the problem too... Thanks for helping in improving my question etc

Comment: `\SearchForOptimal` (do you mean 'optional'?) is applied to `\printArgs`. So the next token is `\ ` and not `[`. Hence, `\relax`.

Comment: You aren't, mostly, using LaTeX 2e, of course. `\def` and friends aren't LaTeX. And you are also using engine-specific macros.

Comment: @cfr, thanks... Yes.. I mean optional... \def is a command I can not avoid to manage to do all these I want to do... Also pdf@strcmp is a way to have the same code for LaTeX and XeLaTeX... but I haven't check that yet... I don't really know which macros I used are engine-specific macros...

Comment: Well, I assume from the name that one is engine-specific and won't work with, say, `latex`.

Comment: My point about `\def` was just that you have already given up on a 2e approach. That's perfectly sensible, but then you are going the TeX route as opposed to the LaTeX one offered by L3. That will generally mean less readable code and the need to take much more responsibility for checks. And spurious spaces, of  course.

Comment: May be it is time to move to LaTeX3 before learning LaTeX2e... Thank you! I will think about it a little bit more...

Comment: I'd urge you _not_ to have document commands with this type of syntax: experience strongly suggests the signature of commands should be well-defined. If you need variable lists of arguments, use comma  lists, keyval syntax, _etc._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an `x` to see the problem:

```
\def\SearchForOptimal{%
   \@ifnextchar[%
   {\FoundOptimal}%
   {x\relax}%
}
```

[image: 'x' marks the spot]

The next character in this case is `\` and not `[`. Hence, the 'if false' condition is used, `x\relax`.

Note that the problem has nothing to do with the use of the arguments. Try

```
\def\mytestcommand{%
\xdef\MaxMandArgs{2}%
\SearchForOptimal
x
}
```

for comparison. The way you have `\SearchForOptimal` written, it has to be the last thing in `\mytestcommand`.

Comment: Thanks @cfr this explains exactly my problem... Of course doesn't solve it, but I don't think there is an easy solution... I will try today to find a solution and will come back to  accept your answer if I will not find a real solution... Probably my way is much more difficult than I expected....

Comment: Thanks... your answer gave me the answer to what was wrong and have fixed that. Also thanks for the discussions about `L3`, `keyval` and `xparse` etc

Answer (score 5):

Something like this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{NumOptionalArgFound}
\newcounter{NumMandatoryArgFound}

\newcommand\MaxMandArgs{3}% default value

\makeatletter

\newcommand\SearchForArguments {%
   \setcounter{NumOptionalArgFound}{0}%
   \setcounter{NumMandatoryArgFound}{0}%
   \@SearchForOptional
}

% fetching optional arguments

\newcommand\@SearchForOptional{%
    \kernel@ifnextchar[\@FoundOptional\@SearchForMandatory
}

\def\@FoundOptional[#1]{%
   \stepcounter{NumOptionalArgFound}%
   \global\@namedef{OptionalArgument\arabic{NumOptionalArgFound}}{#1}%
   \@SearchForOptional
}

% fetching mandatory arguments

% I do not quite understand this \bgroup business but aiming
% to be close to OP. It actually complicates things a lot because
% one can not use a \futurelet to distinguish \bgroup from {

\newcommand\@SearchForMandatory[1]{%
    \edef\@tempKola{\detokenize{#1}}%
    \edef\@tempKolb{\detokenize{\bgroup}}%
    \ifx\@tempKola\@tempKolb
      \expandafter\@firstofone
    \else
      \ifnum\value{NumMandatoryArgFound}<\MaxMandArgs %<- must leave a space
       \stepcounter{NumMandatoryArgFound}%
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@GetMandatoryAndGoOn
      \else
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstofone
      \fi
    \fi {#1}%
}

\newcommand\@GetMandatoryAndGoOn[1]{%
    \global\@namedef{MandatoryArgument\arabic{NumMandatoryArgFound}}{#1}%
    \@SearchForMandatory
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\printArgs{{\color{blue}%
Value of MaxMandArgs: \MaxMandArgs

\ifnum\value{NumOptionalArgFound}>0
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\theNumOptionalArgFound}{%
  Opt Arg \i: \csname OptionalArgument\i\endcsname\par
}\fi

\ifnum\value{NumMandatoryArgFound}>0
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\theNumMandatoryArgFound}{%
  Mand Arg \i: \csname MandatoryArgument\i\endcsname\par
}\fi
}}

\newcommand\mytestcommand[1]{\gdef\MaxMandArgs{#1}\SearchForArguments}

\begin{document}

\mytestcommand{2}[Optional 1][Optional Second]{first Mand}{second Mand}{third Mand}\bgroup noMand \egroup

\printArgs

\mytestcommand{3}[O1][O2][O3][O4]{M1}{M2}{M3}{M4}{M5}\bgroup STOP\egroup

\printArgs

\end{document}
```

[image]

What is in black is what has not been considered part of the thing.

One could modify the macros above to not swallow the arguments it identifies as either optional or mandatory.

There is a powerful package called `xparse` which seems indicated here.

And with

```
\mytestcommand{6}[O1][O2][O3][O4]{M1}{M2}{M3}{M4}{M5}\bgroup STOP\egroup

\printArgs
```

[image]

Comment: the test for ``NumMandatoryArgFound``  should be located after the step counter so that the macro knows it must stop after having recorded that last found mandatory argument and it should look like ``\ifnum\value{NumMandatoryArgFound}=\MaxMandArgs<space>``. With current code we go unneedlessly one beyond. But I was sticking close to OP...

Comment: Thanks jfbu, much better than my code... You just forgot to solve the problem :)... I have already found the solution after @cfr's answer... The solution I am talking about is to add '\printArgs' or something with Args inside the definition of command So that I can use the command as standalone command and not to need '\printArgs' or whatever after that. Also all the definitions this way can be used for as many commands as I want... The solution is to add a function \ExecuteCommand or something similar inside 'SearchForMandatory'... ExecuteCom can contain in csname the name of the function...

Comment: great that you solved your problem. I must admit I did not quite understand what it was exactly ;-) but that does not matter.

Comment: \bgroup is there to make sure that the user of my command can use \bgroup after giving my command and the content of \bgroup \egroup will not be ounted as a mandatory argument...

Comment: `\bgroup` is not likely to be used by casual LaTeX user. It is important for `\vbox` or `\toks` things in various contexts.

Comment: `\bgroup...\egroup` would never be an argument of a TeX macro. Only the first token `\bgroup` will be fetched (and subsequent ones possibly)

Comment: ok... thanks for the information... I suppose I made the things more complex than needed... If you want add an \ExecuteCommand in place of {#1} in your searchForMandatory... I think if it is defined as \printArgs will give the same results and will have my problem solved

Comment: You can use an approach like the above to fetch arbitrarily many **optional** arguments, then just use a `\newcommand\GetMandatories[3]{...}` for example if the macro will have `3` mandatory arguments. Having a non-prescribed in advance number of mandatory arguments looks self-contradictory ... or then you need some definitive end-marker, but do not use `\bgroup` for that.

Comment: However I would certainly go with @JosephWright comment that if the number of optional arguments is not fixed, it is much better to use some other approach, e.g. key-value syntax.

Comment: I think you should look at xparse package.

Comment: Yes... Something like this I had in mind... And for such reason I tried this approach of the command... For example to add vertically as much numbers as I want... I did knew that \bgroup is not used often and just put it there to ensure my code will not consider it as a an argument... And thanks for the advice about @JosephWright's comment... I just wanted to have one more option and want to learn some more things on def...

Comment: @koleygr I'd third the suggestion about `xparse`. I didn't suggest it because it is L3. Since you're loading it anyway, you could also use `pgfkeys` to provide key-value syntax. I find it much trickier than L3's version, but that is probably just me.

Comment: thanks for the comment @cfr it was usefull. I will play around a couple of days and come back to finish (accept) some answers... (I have another similar question awaiting for acceptance, but I was looking to get more info and answer after that.) This topic will wait one or two days too