# Add marks in a table of exam

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, enumerate

Please I want modify the following code by adding a new command as `\marks{7,6,4,3}` to get

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphics} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\tikzstyle{NP}=[rectangle,  
draw=blue!80,
rounded corners=1pt, 
inner sep=12pt,
inner ysep=4pt,
draw, fill=black!0,
text width=2cm,
minimum height=.9cm]


\newcommand{\TS}[1]{ 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle,draw=blue!80,rounded corners=1pt,inner sep=60pt,  inner ysep=16pt, minimum height=6cm, text width=10cm,align=center,] 
    {
        \begin{enumerate}[]
        \itemsep.1em
        \item
        \foreach \x in {1, ...,#1}{\item{ 
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node[NP, fill=black!05](abc){\bfseries   \x};
                \node[NP,   right=of abc]{};
                \end{tikzpicture}
        }}%
    \end{enumerate}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
%\marks{7,6,4,3}
\TS{4}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will there always be only four arguments for `\marks`? Do you only want the blue boxes with the arguments of `\marks` to show up or do you still want the results from `\TS` and just another box right next to it? Please be a bit more specific.

Comment: @Sito Not only for 4 arguments. This is depends to the number of  exercises in the exam.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\ts}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={draw, rounded corners, minimum width=15mm, minimum height=6mm}]
\foreach \i [count=\ni] in {#1}{
    \node[box] at (0,-\ni) (l\ni) {\ni};
    \node[box, text=red, font=\bfseries, right= 3mm of l\ni] (r\ni) {\i};}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\ts{7,3,4,6}

\ts{2,3,4}

\ts{5,6,8,9,10}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The basic idea for this comes from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448877/check-number-of-arguments-in-a-command) post. Please note that you need the `listofitems` package, which you can be downloaded [here](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/listofitems). I just wanted to extend the definition of `\TS` in such a way that the second argument can be read by `\readlist`. Then you just create a list called `\mark` which can be accessed over a index.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphics} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{listofitems}


\tikzstyle{NP}=[rectangle,  
draw=blue!80,
rounded corners=1pt, 
inner sep=12pt,
inner ysep=4pt,
draw, fill=black!0,
text width=2cm,
minimum height=.9cm]

\newcommand{\TS}[2]{%
    \readlist*\mark{#2}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle,draw=blue!80,rounded corners=1pt,inner sep=60pt,  inner ysep=16pt, text width=10cm,align=center] 
    {
        \begin{enumerate}[]
        \itemsep.1em
        \item
        \foreach \x in {1, ...,#1}{\item{ 
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node[NP, fill=black!05](abc){\bfseries   \x};
                \node[NP, right=of abc]{\mark[\x]};
                \end{tikzpicture}
        }}%
        \end{enumerate}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\TS{4}{7,6,4,3}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user105476 You‘re welcome! If you need the marks to be in red and bold, feel free to say so. I‘ll edit it in.